# Patch request using Retrofit2 not working Android

Tags: android, http, retrofit2

I have created patch request using Retrofit2.

```
@PATCH("/tests/{id}")
Call<Test> updateTest(@Path("id") int id, @Body Test test);
```

This request working using Postman. It returns updated JSON of Test class. But it is not working using Retrofit.

Any help ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting.

Comment: post your error log

Comment: I am not getting an error. I am getting success but value is not updated on server.

Comment: Have you check your request by printing it in log??

Comment: Found my mistake. Need to add "/" after {id} in URL. Same URL (means without slash) is working for GET but not working for PATCH.

Comment: @KhushbuShah was it just slash... how did you worked to get the response from the server.. I couldn't get the response as in postman using retrofit

Comment: @DilipPoudel API will give same response in both Retrofit and Postman. please explain your scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "/" at the end of URL.

```
@PATCH("/tests/{id}/")
```

Answer (score 0):

well you should display your error but in general in retrofit you should pass your path parameter before so it will be something like this

```
@PATCH("/tests/{id}")
Call<Test> updateTest(@Path("id") int id, @Body Test test);
```

hope this helps

Comment: Also tried with this. Both are giving success but the value is not updated on server. I will update this in question so none will get conused..

Answer (score 0):

please check method (GET , POST , DELETE) and change code to :

```
@GET("/tests/{id}")
```